# Regex: Replace WITH REPEATED strings , not "replace repeat"

Tags: regex, replace, repeat

Could we replace a matched pattern with a REPEATED pattern USING regular expression?

For example :
the target string is "abc2:4def" , what I want is `abc2222def`, that means the "4" is a repeater in the target string and I want to compose my string back to "uncompressed" format.

I could think of the back reference in `sed`,

```
sed 's/\([0-9]+\):\([0-9]\)/\1\\{\2\\}/' #\1 to match "2" and \2 to match "4".
```

`\\{n\\}` is to repeat n times, but unfortunately that does not work.

I am wondering if it could be supported by `REGEX`. Any advise ?

I know we could achieve it by other tools, but at hand, I could only use some `REGEX` functions.

This is my first post in stackoverflow, please let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

In `Perl`, I'm able to do the trick :

```
$ echo abc2:4def | perl -lne 'print $1 . $2 x $3 . $4 if m/^(\w+)(\d):(\d)(.*)/;'
abc2222def
```

Comment: True that, but the "multiplication" is not a regex, but a code feature. :)

Comment: If you find this in a REGEX, welcome, and come again to tell me how.